# prevent Random PHP generator from including zeros

Tags: php, random

I have a php script that creates a random 10 digit order number:

```
// Assign order number length
$digits = 10;

// Create random order number to be stored with this order
$order_number = rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);
```

How do I prevent this from ever including the digit zero `0` in the random 10 digit number? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you are using `pow()` as argument for `rand()`for creating random numbers?

Comment: @djot: To calculate a range based on a given number of digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple function like this:

```
function getRandom($length) {
    $numbers = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $numbers .= rand(1, 9);
    }
    return $numbers;
}

echo getRandom(10);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do fancy base conversions, but in the end, the most straightforward way is to just get a string:

```
function random_string($count, $available) {
    $result = '';
    $max = strlen($available) - 1;

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $result .= $available[rand(0, $max)];
    }

    return $result;
}

…
$order_number = random_string($digits, '123456789');
```

Comment: This does not answer the question; if `rand(0, 9)` returns `0`, the number will contain a 0. I think you meant `rand(1, 9)`.

Comment: Or just keep the zero out of the `$digits` string…

Comment: Then you'd need to change the `rand()` call to `rand(0, 8)` :) Personally I wouldn't bother with `$digits` and use the result of `rand()` directly (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

You can treat it as a number of base 9

```
base_convert(rand(0, pow(9, $digits) - 1), 10, 9)
```

This will give you numbers with digits from 0 to 8.

Now just add 1 to every digit to make it 1 to 9

```
(pow(10, $digits) - 1) / 9
```

will give you a number filled with ones. Now just add it to your previous number and there you go:

```
$digits = 10;

$order_number = (pow(10, $digits) - 1) / 9 + base_convert(rand(0, pow(9, $digits) - 1), 10, 9);
```

Comment: and where did this 9 come from?

Comment: Oh way, base 9! I take it back, smart one. =)

Comment: However this will not work with 10 digit numbers because php's `rand` and `mt_rand` functions are limited. There is a simple workaround for this to just concatenate two 5 digit numbers or just the last digit with `. rand(1,9)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this :D

```
function getRandom($from, $to){
    $num = rand($from, $to);
    $have_zero = true;
    $strNum = strval($num);
    while ($have_zero){
        $have_zero = false;
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($strNum); $i++){
            if ($strNum[$i] == '0'){
                $have_zero = true;
                $num = rand($from, $to);
                $strNum = strval($num);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $num;
}
getRandom(1111111111, 9999999999);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make a function.

```
<?php

function myRandomNumberWithoutZeros($digits)
{
    $result = str_replace("0", "",rand(pow(10,$digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1)."");
    $resultLength = strlen($result);
    if($resultLength < $digits)
    {
        return intval($result.myRandomNumberWithoutZeros($digits-$resultLength));
    }
    return intval($result); 
}
echo myRandomNumberWithoutZeros(10);

?>
```